# What problem-solving skills are essential for the Allen AI Science Challenge?

Tags: problem-solving, artificial-intelligence

Recently, many in cognitive science and machine learning circles are very interested in the '[The Allen AI Science Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-allen-ai-science-challenge)' that was recently announced. Here is a brief description:

> The [Allen Institute for Artificial Intelligence](http://allenai.org/index.html) (AI2) is working to
>   improve humanity through fundamental advances in artificial
>   intelligence. One critical but challenging problem in AI is to
>   demonstrate the ability to consistently understand and correctly
>   answer general questions about the world.
>
> The [Aristo project](http://aristo-demo.allenai.org/#/) at AI2 is focused on building such a system. One
>   way Aristo "learns" is by extracting facts from various sources and
>   processing them into a structured knowledge base. When taking an exam,
>   questions are parsed and processed along with any accompanying
>   diagrams to determine a strategy for answering. Aristo then uses
>   entailment, statistical analysis, and inference methods to select a
>   final answer.
>
> While Aristo's abilities have improved significantly in the last two
>   years, it still doesn't have perfect, reliable methods of gathering
>   knowledge, understanding questions, or reasoning through answers.
>
> Using a dataset of multiple choice question and answers from a
>   standardized 8th grade science exam, AI2 is challenging you to create
>   a model that gets to the head of the class.

**What problem solving and reasoning skills do you feel a computer will need to get past a 8th grade MCQ standardized science test?**

**What are, or what do you think are the obstacles present in present in training computers to master these cognitive abilities?**

**And to throw in a subjective question, do you think that someone will be able match this task given the present state of Artificial Intelligence?** 
 
[Note that most Jeopardy! questions asked to IBM Watson were wikipedia searchable entries]